# SQL query to criteria nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, criteria-api, nhibernate-criteria

Hello. I have a problem with the creation of a Hibernate Criteria object. I'm new to Hibernate.

Can someone help me with the creation of a complex Criteria object and explain how this is done? Here is the sample SQL `select` statement to emulate:

`select * from Company join Employees on Company.IDCompany  = Employees.IDCompany;`

Comment: wats ur question... Make it clear to us ....

Comment: i wanna make criteria from that sql query with all prosperties of Company and all properties of Employees that join on IDCompany. return as ICollection or IList

Comment: can u post some sample data n ur desired o/p

Comment: what do u mean? Do you want c# properties declarations of 2 classes?

Comment: We can't assume questions and give answers here.... U need to post the question properly....

Comment: Have you done the slightest bit of research before asking? The [docs](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria) would be a good place to start

Comment: Thx i was looking for that, and yes i was looking whole day... Starts are always bad;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user NH3 you can use QueryOver instead of ICriteria, as for me QueryOver expressions are better than ICriteria strings.

```
Session.QueryOver<Company>()
 .JoinQueryOver(company => company.Employees)
 .Where(...) // some restrictions
 .List<Company>();
```

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

Comment: <code> session.QueryOver<Company>().JoinQueryOver((Company=> Company.Employees)).Where(Company.IDCompany = Employees.IDCompany).List<Company>(); </code>
It show's me that Connot resolve symbol Employees so it wont work;/

Comment: "Employees" should be a class property name, for example:
class Company
{
  public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
}